# How to edit wrong (x,y,z)position in matplotlib graph with mouse(python)?

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, editor, coordinates

y,z coordinates from pose estimation code results and for a graph that will allow me to correct or edit the wrong x,y,z using mouse drag and drop for each joint(spot) position.

---

here under is what I'm looking for and for your easy reference.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo23B.jpg]

---

Thus, my Question is

1. Is matplotlib serves to correct and edit each coordinates using mouse drag&drop?
2. if possible, how can I apply code to correct?? If you show me an example by using only three coordinates(x,y,z) and I could apply for whole bodyparts.
3. if not possible, should i use GUI tools such as PyQt5 and embedding matplotlib graph?

Can someone help me?

---

This is the x,y,z coordinates for each joints I have.

```
Points = 
[ -11.64237375   10.75849817 -103.79065128]
[ -11.64237375   10.75849817 -103.79065128]
[ -11.64237375   10.75849817 -103.79065128]
[ -99.31704537 -101.46516131 -120.29617922]
[-134.8242598  -121.9056413  -573.94744542]
[-164.78443965  -21.85242667 -944.78896293]
[  90.65356524  122.98237098 -117.79036415]
[  54.57272985   92.79299907 -536.40653534]
[  20.13418653  150.64142751 -943.28973025]
[-20.30577585  22.07276347 188.29588003]
[ 24.86531111 -11.48381142 522.09460156]
[103.79798707 -66.61449726 565.50013896]
[127.53734168 -44.60791096 703.8176707 ]
[ 95.89056707 123.59714541 500.44558514]
[178.06204746 269.14908908 294.44593009]
[342.51351482 204.85274919 238.91231928]
[ -95.40482399 -115.46323437  498.61541371]
[-231.43566863 -197.70211227  236.9739531 ]
[-208.46302635 -291.33858304  -13.69032204]
```

Comment: see this: https://github.com/yuma-m/matplotlib-draggable-plot

Comment: Checkout the matplotlib documentation. https://matplotlib.org/gallery/event_handling/poly_editor.html

Comment: Thanks bro i modified your reference code.